# Truncate SKU in invoice

Tags: invoice, pdf, sku

How can I use substr to truncate the SKU of Magento's invoices? The relevant code is:

```
    // draw SKU
    $lines[0][] = array(
        'text' => Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($this->getSku($item), 19),
        'feed' => $pdf->margin['left'] + 25,
        'font_size' => $fontSize
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The following returns the first 19 characters of $sku.

```
substr($sku, 0, 19);
```

Comment: Thanks, but where would I place this in the code?